# regular expression for minimu two words

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make a real name check, and should at last 2 normal words (a-z).

E.g:
If input is:

```
'real name' => true
'real name real and many words' => true
'name' => false
```

I have this regex but it seems to don't work

```
^[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+$
```

Any help? regexp for minim two words in javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there.  Put `\s` and the following `[a-zA-Z]+` into a capturing or non-capturing group and make them to repeat  one or more times by adding a `+` quantifier next to that group.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+)+$
```

Example:

```
> /^[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('real name')
true
> /^[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('real name real and many words')
true
> /^[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+)+$/.test('name')
false
```

Comment: Raj can you make one that all word should contain at last 3 letters?

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z]{3,}(?:\s[a-zA-Z]{3,})+$` https://regex101.com/r/sV8yT8/4 ie, nstead of `+`, use `{3,}` ensures that the word contains atleast three letters.